# Открывать картинки во весь экран

Tags: java, android

Есть картинки, которые добавляю в список из галереи.

Хочу чтоб по нажатию на них, они открывались во весь экран.

Как возможно это сделать правильно?

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Фотки смотришь из галереи - то-есть все что на девайсе есть?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko  именно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

Создаете `ImageActivity`:

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int imageId = extras.getInt("image_id");
            mImageView.setImageResource(imageId);
        }
    }
}
```

Ее `layout` **activity_image.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

При необходимости показа картинки – запускаете `ImageActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image_id", R.drawable.my_image);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: супер, только опять же, если у меня много картинок, то и в  mImageView.setImageResource и intent.putExtra мы должны прописать путь к гетеру в модели?

Comment: @Inkognito, Типа того, но только при создании интента.

Answer (score 1):

Просто передай через `Intent` в `Activity` (в которой будешь это фото показывать) `Uri`, а потом получи Bitmap картинки:

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("IMAGE_URI"); // IMAGE_URI - ключт
InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```